# Difference between k and m in mysql variables

Tags: mysql

What means 6 k or 6 m in value of mysql variables ?

Ex :

i have Qcache_queries_in_cache = 6 k ; = 6000

But 6 m = ? or 6 G ?

Thanks

Comment: k = kilobytes; m = megabytes; g = gigabytes etc.

Comment: k is usually a thousand, m a million, g a billion...

Comment: Although small m is usually milli, i.e. `10^-3`.